# Is there a css min-top property

Tags: css

Is there any css property like min-height, but for top?
In the example below, when i hide div1 (via javascript), i want div2 to have top:50. Else, to be placed below div1.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1
{
height:100px;
}
#div2{
//min-top:50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='div1'>This div may be hidden</div>
<div id='div2'>This div must not be placed above 50px</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: as i answered below

> When div1 is not hidden i want div2 to be exactly below div1. imagine div1 as a treeview which can have any height (or even be hidden) and div2 as a paragraph which should always be below 50px

Comment: You mean `margin-top` or `padding-top`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this question has still many views and people are still commenting. Because of the fact that the question is not fully answered, i decided to write here the complete answer:

**Appropriate css:**

```
#div1 {
    min-height:50px;
    background-color: #fee;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
#div2 {
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: #efe
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/5051/

**Results**

- When div1 is hidden, div2 has a top property of 50px
- When div1 is not hidden:

  - If div1 height is less than 50px, then div2 is placed at 50px
  - If div1 height is more than 50px, then div2 is placed right under div1

Comment: Nice, clever use of margins. Although this could be further improved so that `#div2` applies styles if it is directly preceded by `#div1` using [css3 selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) `#div2 { margin-top: 50px; } #div1 + #div2 { margin-top: 0 }`

Answer (score 9):

"Is there a css min-top property?" no, but ...

... you can use math function to take effect like min-top:

```
<style> 
  #div2{
    top:max(50px, 10%);
  }
</style>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max

Answer (score 6):

I came up with this solution which utilises the top:0 bottom:0 hack.

We create a container the height of it's relative parent (if any) - we then give this a min-height (eg your min-top)

We then position the actual element absolutely to the bottom on this container.

CSS:

```
.container {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 700px; //Adjust this to your MINIMUM (eg your min-top)
}

.position-me {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="position-me">Great!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working when the min-height is less than the height of the window
http://jsfiddle.net/gxp05jk5/

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your problem, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: The problem has been solved with the answer of xpy with my comment on his answer

Comment: Works like a charn and is much better than setting absolute `height` for DOM elements. The `min-height` could be set by any calculation of window height therefore is much more flexible solution.

Answer (score 4):

No there's nothing like `min-top`

Instead you can use is

```
div {
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
}
```

And for the example you shown `visibility: hidden;` will be best suited here, as it will reserve the space of your hidden `div`

Comment: if i do this, then div2 will have top:150 when div1 is not hidden(always 50 more than div1) and top:50 when div1 id hidden. When div1 is not hidden i want div2 to be exactly below div1. imagine div1 as a treeview which can have any height and div2 as a paragraph which should always be below 50px

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis JS is the only option else use `visibility: hidden` to hide as well as reserve space for the element

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this will do the trick for you but I believe it is not a very good practice:

```
#div1
{
    height:100px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
#div2{
    margin-top:50px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/tbbvU/

( Just comment/uncomment the `display:none` to see it work.)

Comment: there is a problem when i write too much stuff in div1. check demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/tbbvU/2/

Comment: problem solved if you replace "height:100px" with "min-height:50px"

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    if ($('#div1').css('display', 'none')){
     $("#div2").addClass('minTop');
 } else if ($('#div1').css('display', 'block')){
    $("#div2").removeClass('minTop');
 }
}).resize();
```

```css
#div1{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:#ff0000;
position:absolute;
display:block;
/* display:none; */
}
#div2{
width:100px;
background-color:#ffff00;
top:150px;
position:absolute;
}
#div2.minTop{
  top:50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id='div1'>div 1</div>
<div id='div2'>div 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer, but a little explanation text would be nice

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using `position: sticky`

See also [solution using margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552358/is-there-a-css-min-top-property/75464901#75464901).

To achieve somewhat similar you can use `position: sticky`. It's not exactly same as top-min would have ideally been, but it can be tweaked cleverly with parent styles to achieve what you have in mind.

```css
.sticky {
  /* Note: The parent element must have a non-default position set too. */
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

*Note: The parent of `position:sticky` element must have a non-default `position` set as well.*

What this does is that when the element moves up by either scrolling, reducing viewport height or layout changes, it will stick to the defined position and will not move until the parent element itself crosses the boundary and **pushes the element out of the way** (as seen in animation below).

[image]

```js
const toggle = () => div1.classList.toggle('hidden')
const toggleSticky = () => div2.classList.toggle('sticky')
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

section {
  /* Note: The parent of position:sticky element must have a non-default position set. */
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id='div1'>This div may be hidden</div>
  <div id='div2' class="sticky">This div must not be placed above 50px</div>
</section>

<aside>
  <button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Toggle #div1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="toggleSticky()">Toggle #div2 sticky</button>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using margins

See also [solution using `position:sticky`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552358/is-there-a-css-min-top-property/75464534#75464534).

The following solution uses a [css3 selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) *"directly preceded by"* or *"placed immediately after"* and it works by toggling a predetermined class (`.hidden` in this example) on the preceding element.

```css
#div1.hidden + #div2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

```js
const toggle = () => div1.classList.toggle('hidden')
```

```css
#div1.hidden + #div2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id='div1'>This div may be hidden</div>
  <div id='div2'>This div must not be placed above 50px</div>
</section>

<aside>
  <button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Toggle #div1</button>
</aside>
```